# prblem with post on page of facebook with api

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I wrote a code for post a message on my page (not own timeline)

**post.php**

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

session_start();

$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  'app_secret' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.5',
]);

$data = [
  'message' => 'My awesome photo upload example.',
];

try {
  // Returns a `Facebook\FacebookResponse` object
  $response = $fb->post('/xxxxxxxxxxxxxx/feed', $data, $_SESSION['facebook_access_token']);
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
  echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
  echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
}

$graphNode = $response->getGraphNode();

echo 'Photo ID: ' . $graphNode['id'];
```

**index.php**

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

session_start();

$app_id = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
$app_secret = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx';

$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => $app_id,
  'app_secret' => $app_secret,
  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.4',
  'default_access_token' => isset($_SESSION['facebook_access_token']) ? $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'] : 'APP-ID|APP-SECRET'
]);

try {
  $response = $fb->get('/xxxxxxxxxxxxxx?fields=id,name');
  $user = $response->getGraphUser();
  echo 'Name: ' . $user['name'];
  //exit; //redirect, or do whatever you want
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
  echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
  echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
$permissions = ['email', 'user_likes', 'manage_pages', 'publish_actions'];
$loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl('http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxx/facebook/login-callback.php', $permissions);
echo '<a href="' . $loginUrl . '">Log in with Facebook!</a>';
```

**login-callback.php**

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

session_start();

$app_id = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
$app_secret = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx';

$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => $app_id,
  'app_secret' => $app_secret,
  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.4',
  'default_access_token' => 'APP-ID|APP-SECRET'
]);

$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();

try {
  $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
  // When Graph returns an error
  //echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
  // When validation fails or other local issues
  //echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

if (isset($accessToken)) {
  // Logged in!
  $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'] = (string) $accessToken;
} elseif ($helper->getError()) {
  // The user denied the request
}
header('Location: index.php');
```

It's just work when in file `post.php` use this code:

```
$response = $fb->post('/me/feed', $data, $_SESSION['facebook_access_token']);
```

And then post show on my timeline.

But when I want to post on page and use this:

```
$response = $fb->post('/xxxxxxxxxxxxxx/feed', $data, $_SESSION['facebook_access_token']);
```

don't work and not appears anythings, and don't show my post on the page or timeline!

Comment: You need to use a page access token

Comment: Make sure you're using the right permissions when generating the login url

A user access token with publish_actions permission can be used to publish new posts on behalf of that person. Posts will appear in the voice of the user.
A page access token with publish_pages permission can be used to publish new posts on behalf of that page. Posts will appear in the voice of the page.

Comment: @WizKid, @Pazuzu156
You are said correct, but the problem is when login to facebook and get `facebook_access_token`, It's for logged user (not for  page access), Now how can I give facebook access token of the page after login?! For testing I use of `Graph API Explorer` and select page and get Access Token and use it directly (Without user login), but I give this error: `Graph returned an error: Invalid appsecret_proof provided in the API argument` and...

Comment: @WizKid, @Pazuzu156
... and for resolve it, In `src\Facebook\FacebookRequest.php` file, commented line #470 (`$params['appsecret_proof'] = $this->getAppSecretProof();`), after it I post message on page success. But this is not good solution.

Comment: Don't use graph explorer. Read the documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/access-tokens

Comment: @WizKid I know, but in above source code I use own app, but dont works, do you can provide a simple code for upload a photo on my page?!